# load image in iframe using jquery

Tags: jquery, image, iframe, load

I need to display an image in an iframe from a dynamically generated string. The iframe's id is `upload_target`.

This is the code I'm using

```
// assign esrc and upath
$.ajax 
({  type: "POST", 
    url: "editImage.php", 
    data:  {esrc: editsource, upath: upath } ,  
    success: function(esource) 
    {   //load into iframe 
        s = esource;
        console.log(s);
        $('#upload_target').contents().find('body').html(s);
    } 
});
```

The file editImage.php simply returns the right file name. The console shows up the right filename, so I know there's no problem there. But nothing happens to the iframe, it just stays as blank as ever. I was able to populate the same iframe with another event, namely the submission of a form whose `target` was this iframe. But why isn't it working here?

I also tried `$('#upload_target').attr('src',s)`, but I got a 406 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I just hacked a crazy fix. I don't know if it's reasonable but it works.
Instead of using ajax, I just created a form with hidden inputs holding the values I needed to pass on to `editImage.php` and submitted that form. The iframe loaded the image fine then.

```
$('#imgdialog').append("<form id='imageeditform' method='post' action='editImage.php' target='upload_target'><input type='hidden' name='esrc' value='"+editsource+"' /><input type='hidden' name='upath' value='"+$('#upath').val()+"' /></form>");
$('#imageeditform').submit();
```

Answer (score 3):

try

```
...find("body").append($("<img/>").attr("src", s).attr("title", "sometitle"));
```

I didn't debug this code but should work.

**Edit**

This code works fine for me

```
<iframe id="upload_target"><html><body></body></html></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#upload_target').contents().find('body').append($("<img/>").attr("src", "http://www.bing.com/az/hprichbg/rb/NYBirds_ROW10420117938_1366x768.jpg").attr("title", "sometitle"));
    });
</script>
```